# Как получить доступ к объекту модели в кастомном виджете в админке Django?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django, django-admin, виджет

Здравствуйте! Я написал собственный виджет для характеристик в админке.

```
from django.forms.widgets import Widget
from django.template import loader
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from . import models as md

class CharsWidget(Widget):
    template_name = 'widgets/chars_widget.html'

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs=None):

        context = {
            'chars': md.Char.objects.all(),
        }
        return context

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        template = loader.get_template(self.template_name).render(context)
        return mark_safe(template)

    @staticmethod
    def save_chars_values(chars_values):
        product = md.Product.objects.latest('add_date')
        chars_values = map(int, chars_values)
        product.char_values.add(*chars_values)
        product.save()
```

HTML код:

```
<div style="display: inline-block">
    {% for char in chars %}
        <p>
            <label>{{ char.title }}</label>
            <select name="char_values" class="char_values">
                {% for value in char.values.all %}
                    <option value="{{ value.id }}">{{ value.title }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Выглядит это все вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Затем я отображаю его в админке следующим образом:

```
class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    chars_field = forms.CharField(
        widget=widgets.CharsWidget(),
        label='Характеристики',
        required=False
    )

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProductAdminForm

    fields = ('maker', 'sizes', 'chars_field', 'categories', 'title', 'art', 'color_name', 'color_value',
              'description', 'sale_count', 'views_count', 'external_id', 'add_date')

    list_display = ('title', 'maker', 'art', 'description', 'sale_count')
    raw_id_fields = ('maker',)
    filter_horizontal = ('char_values', 'sizes')
    inlines = [StorageQtyProductInline, ProductPriceInline ,ProductImageInline]
    readonly_fields = ('sale_count', 'views_count', 'external_id', 'add_date')

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super().save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        chars_values = request.POST.getlist('char_values')
        widgets.CharsWidget.save_chars_values(chars_values)
```

И сохраняю выбранные характеристики перезаписав метод save_related.
Все хорошо, все работает, но когда я отображаю виджет у уже созданного объекта модели я не знаю как получить к этому объекту доступ. Доступ нужен, чтобы понять какие характеристики у этого объекта модели выбраны и отобразить их в html как selected.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на то, [как работает Widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Widget). Виджет - это обертка, которая отвечает за представление поля в шаблоне. Значение поля передается в `value` параметре. Доступ к объекту, чье поле меняете, вы не получите.

Вы могли бы воспользоваться [MultiWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget) и создать виджет из N-го числа виджетов со своим набором вариантов выбора